# How can i open Kendo model popup on a button click and also close it using a button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, popup

I have created a Kendo model popup and i want to click a button or hyperlink for it to open and also add a close button on the model. For now it only load the the model once i run the form without clicking the button and it works fine but thats not how i want it. I am new to kendo and am trying to learn it.

1. User must click show model to open the button
2. model open up
3. on the model there's two buttons. close and save
4. user must click close and the modal must close.

I have tried the following,

**Model View**

```
<div class="form-group form-horizontal custom-form">
            <label id="txtDate"> Date:</label>
            <div id="calendar2" class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="date" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtDate">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnClose" type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>

 </div>
```

**Button which must call the model view**

```
<div>
<button type="button" id="showModal" class="btn btn-primary">Show   Model</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
            title: "Edit Roles", 
            maxHeight: 500,
            maxWidth: 400,
            position: {
                top: 450,  
                left: "50%"  
            },               
            resizable: false, 
            scrollable: false, 
            modal: true, 

            close: function () {
                $("#dialog").kendoWindow()
                var win = this;
                $('#btnClose').click(function () {
                    win.close();
                    alert("closed")
                })
            }
        });
    });
       </script>
```

Comment: Could you make this as a plunkr so we can edit it?

Comment: @VasilDininski i dont understand. can you please rephrase? thanks

Comment: @VasilDininski are you there. I cant get it right,can you please help me?